# Dijkstra's Algorithm and trouble with A* algorithm

Tags: java

So I have been searching these two algorithms on the Internet and was able to, after days of working on it, get Dijkstra's Algorithm working. From what I have read the two Algorithms are not that different. So I am going to post what I did for Dijkstra's and I was hoping that you can show me or point me into the direction on how to modify it to the A* algorithm.

```
public Integer processGraph(int graph[][], int algorithm, int s, int d) {


    if(algorithm == 1) {


        // shortestDist[index] will hold the distance from s to the index
        int shortestDist[] = new int[graph.length];

        // added[i] is true if vertex index is included / the shortest distance from the source to the index is finalized
        boolean added[] = new boolean[graph.length];


        // establish all distances as Integer.Max_Value and added[] as false
        for (int vertexIndex = 0; vertexIndex < graph.length; vertexIndex++) {
            shortestDist[vertexIndex] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            added[vertexIndex] = false;
        }

        // Distance of the source from itself is always 0
        shortestDist[s] = 0;

        // Parent array to store shortest the shortest path -- example: [num, num, num]
        int[] parents = new int[graph.length];


        // Find shortest path for all vertices
        for (int i = 1; i < graph.length; i++) {

            // Pick the minimum distance vertex
            // from the set of vertices not yet
            // processed. nearestVertex is
            // always equal to the source in
            // first iteration.
            int u = minDistance(shortestDist, added);
            added[u] = true;
            for (int vertexIndex = 0; vertexIndex < graph.length; vertexIndex++) {
                if (!added[vertexIndex] && graph[u][vertexIndex] != 0 && shortestDist[u] != Integer.MAX_VALUE && shortestDist[u] + graph[u][vertexIndex] < shortestDist[vertexIndex]) {
                    shortestDist[vertexIndex] = shortestDist[u] + graph[u][vertexIndex];
                    parents[vertexIndex] = u;
                }

            }

        }

        if(shortestDist[d] == Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println("ERROR MESSAGE -- No path present from " + s + " to " + d);
            System.out.println("ERROR MESSAGE --no path present from " + s + " to " + d);
            System.out.println(" ");
            return null;
        }


        //pathPrint(s, shortestDist, d); this only works for the first test
        return shortestDist[d];
    } // end algorithm 1
```

TO add more context to this, I have a driver class in which with several graphs upon which this finds the shortest path.
Example of graph[][]:

```
int regValid[][] = {{0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                        {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                        {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                        {0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                        {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                        {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                        {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                        {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                        {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                        {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
                        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
                        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0},
                        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0},
                        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1},
                        {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}};
```

Again, how can I modify what I have to work with the A* algorithm instead of Dijkstras. Thank you and hopefully this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You have full information about all nodes, edges and destination node, so Dijkstra is the best solution for your problem. A* would be useful if you hadn't known complete graph (most often for huge node space) and were forced to prioritize decisions according to some heuristics.

If you really want to simulate A* on your graph, you have to think out some artificial criterion (heuristics) which describes the estimated distance between given node and target node (in other words, pretend you don't know the path). Since your data set doesn't contain such additional information (and thinking out any satisfying admissibility condition is not trivial), your question doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: A* isn't just for times when you don't know the full graph. It's useful for graphs too large to efficiently use Djikstra's on.